# pulling records from mysql where the difference between 2 dates is greater than 8 days

Tags: mysql

[According to this documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) from my understanding using `INTERVAL 8 DAY` will return any records greater than 8 days.

In my statement `$moztimestampnow` is the current date in this format `2015-05-21` and `moztimestamp` pertains to the column in the DB that contains the other earlier date in which I need to calculate with.

I am not sure if I am able to use `moztimestamp` as the column name in this statement and it is not working.

How do I get the difference in days?

```
$moztimestampnow = date('Y-m-d');
SELECT *,DATEDIFF('$moztimestampnow',moztimestamp) INTERVAL 8 DAYS FROM backlinks WHERE user_id = '$user_id' LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Even assuming that you could, why would you use datediff with interval???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you a misinterpreting the documentation.  The `interval` keyword is for adding values to dates.  If you want to filter data, you need to use the `where` clause.

In your case, the best `where` clause looks like this:

```
SELECT bl.*, DATEDIFF('$moztimestampnow', moztimestamp)
FROM backlinks bl
WHERE user_id = '$user_id' and
      moztimestamp <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 DAY)
LIMIT 10
```

This can take advantage of an index on `backlinks(user_id, moztimestamp)`.  In addition, you probably should have an `ORDER BY` clause.  That is expected when using `LIMIT`.

Comment: You were close, I edited your solution just a tad and that did it man thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax doesn't make sense.  Try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM backlinks
WHERE DATE_SUB(moztimestamp, INTERVAL 8 DAY) > '$moztimestampnow' 
AND user_id = '$user_id'
LIMIT 10
```

I don't follow your objective, so you may have to change the order and direction in the first `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Enclose the variable in inverted commas. 2015-05-21 = 1989